# ProgressBar display abnormal

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need to display ProgressBar in some pages.

this is my code:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

all the ProgressBar are the same. But they ProgressBar showed in activities are different (same device and same android version 4.2.2) . I don't know why! Some of them are the ics style, other of them seem like 2.x style.

any ideas?

ps:I want the first style below. And my app only support android 4.0+.

update--------------------------

My activity's style:

(for the first pic)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

(for the second pic)

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears one activity has a black background and the other has a white background.  Implies that you are setting a different style on at least one of the activities.  How are you doing this?

Comment: @selbie the first pic is from ApiDemo. Because it's a little hard to get a screenshot with ProgressBar with that style in my app. I can show you my activity's style. And I update the questions. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I don't know why! Some of them are the ics style, other of them seem like 2.x style.
```

You are using different theme for each of your activity thus giving your different styles of progress bar for different activities.

**solution:**

If you want all of the progress bar you can use one style for all of your progressbar.

**sample:**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Er... I update my question and add my activity's style there. Am I really use different sytles there?

Comment: @android_su remember all phone have there own default theme, adding `Theme.NoTitleBar` will change the default theme